# Compiling two c files not working, header not found

Tags: c, compilation

I have a problem, when trying to compile two c files from terminal.
Files I have are: main.c user_info.c. They are both in the same folder.
When trying to compile, I use: **gcc main.c user_info.c -o program**
It gives an error message as: 
**main.c:3:10: fatal error: 'user_info.h' file not found**

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "user_info.h"

int main() {

struct user person1;
struct user person2;

person1.userId = 1;
person2.userId = 2;

puts("Enter the first name of user 1");
gets(person1.firstName);
puts("Enter the first name of user 2");
gets(person2.firstName);

printf("User 1 id is %d\n", person1.userId);
printf("User 2 first name is %s\n", person2.firstName);

return 0;
}
```

user_info.c

```
struct user {
int userId;
char firstName[25];
char lastName[25];
int age;
float weight;
};
```

Comment: And what does your header contain if the implementation file contains the `struct` declaration?

Comment: If there isn't a separate source file using the structure, you don't really need the header.  Headers are for sharing information between source files.  However, even if you don't need it yet, you may do in the future, and/or it is part of your training exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have user_info.c not user_info.h. If you are defining a structure, change the name of user_info.c to user_info.h and try compiling main.c.